# OpenCL: float or integer?

Tags: c++, casting, opencl, gpgpu, nvidia

Although there are several questions in float type topic I still have some open points to clarify. I use OpenCL 1.1 (NVIDIA).

I want to **compare numbers** and also **use them as an index of an array**: which is faster?
1.) to use **integers** for both of comparing and indexing
2.) or to use **floats** and do cast when I use it as an index of an array?

Unfortunately I'm not sure which is more expensive; to cast float to integer or compare integers instead of float.

Is there any advantages of using unsigned integers over signed integers?

EDIT: the main reason I'm asking this that I have an OpenCL code (I mean the host code and the kernel code) and it is not as fast as I expected and my first thought it's because of I'm using uint instead of float.

Comment: Why would you want to use floats at all in your scenario?

Comment: I always see that floats are faster and the cores of the GPU card is for float type. As far as I know to add two float or integer requires different hardware architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I would not count on comparing `(int) (FLOAT_MAX - 1)` with `(int) (FLOAT_MAX - 2)`. The result might say, they are equal.

How big are your arrays. Maybe a smaller datatype could fit in, like `half`-floats, or `byte`/`short` instead of `int`?

Comment: The array is very-very big. This is the reason why I want to use the GPU card to process it. It's a graph and the elements of the array are the node numbers at the same time. This is the reason why I use them as an index and do comparing when I check the neighbors. And do you think the smaller type the faster?

Comment: If the array is really very-very-big, how big is the chance it will fit in your OpenCL memory (i.e. graphics memory) at once?

Comment: It's really not sure I'll have enough device memory, but it's another problem and I'll face to this later. For example I'm reading an OpenCL book now and each example uses float and I don't know whether is there any reason behind of this or it's just an example. My friend told me float are faster because the hardware are specific.

Comment: Integer arithmetic is mostly the fastest, followed by single precision real numbers (float)  and finally the slowest are double precision real numbers.  the specific runtime depends on your hardware of course. And GPUs often lack the latter.

Comment: @Christian, AFAIK, integer math is slower that float on GPUs, especially on NVIDIA GPUs. This is why AMD has been the choice for bitcoin mining.

Comment: Wouldn't it depend on the actual operation. You might think of integer comparisons and array indexing (as stated in the question) should be simply bit comparison.

Comment: I also had the thought that in case of NVIDIA the float is better. Of course a measurement would be better. But what about indexing? Is it good to do index with float like: myArray[(float)myVar]  ?? is it expensive? Honestly I have know idea what the compiler does at this point.

Comment: If `myVar` is an int casted to float, your array indexing expression will throw an tangible error.
If you use something like `myArray[myVar_is_a_float]` it might work, but the index should not be too large.

Comment: @Christian: the last one cannot be compiled. this is the reason why I had to use cast float to int. Ohhh, sorry I wanted to write:  myArray[(int)myFloatVar] in my comment ... I modified there too